# In Objective-C, how to print out N spaces? (using stringWithCharacters)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, core-foundation

The following is tried to print out N number of spaces (or 12 in the example):

```
NSLog(@"hello%@world", [NSString stringWithCharacters:" " length:12]);

const unichar arrayChars[] = {' '};
NSLog(@"hello%@world", [NSString stringWithCharacters:arrayChars length:12]);

const unichar oneChar = ' ';
NSLog(@"hello%@world", [NSString stringWithCharacters:&oneChar length:12]);
```

But they all print out weird things such as `hello ÔÅÓñüÔÅ®Óñü®ÓüÅ®ÓñüÔ®ÓüÔÅ®world`... I thought a "char array" is the same as a "string" and the same as a "pointer to a character"?  The API spec says it is to be a "C array of Unicode characters" (by Unicode, is it UTF8?  if it is, then it should be compatible with ASCII)... How to make it work and why those 3 ways won't work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `%*s` to specify the width.

```
NSLog(@"Hello%*sWorld", 12, "");
```

[Reference:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk
>   ( '*' ). In this case an argument of type int supplies the field width
>   or precision. Applications shall ensure that arguments specifying
>   field width, or precision, or both appear in that order before the
>   argument, if any, to be converted.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool. The only downside is that it only works for `NSLog` and `-stringWithFormat:`, which are both pretty slow. But hey, if you want something that 'just works' this is much easier to embed in your application than my answer.

Comment: Ya I am trying to remember the name of it and find a link (hard to google `%*`), I answered this somewhere a while ago. Found it referenced http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: Nice.  say if printing out a line divider, like "=" repeated 72 times, can this be also tweaked or by similar method to make it work?

Comment: No the `*` just allows you to dynamically set the width, whitespace is used for the spacing.

Comment: @Joe ah. Then that is quite the drawback. It's a shame, really.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes, but it definitely answers the question "how to print N spaces?"

Answer (score 17):

This will get you what you want:

```
NSLog(@"hello%@world", [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:12 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: That, my good sir, is not very clear what you are accomplishing, and no code formatting. -1.

Comment: @trudyscousin no worries. Also gave you a +1 cause I found the downvote somewhat unfair.

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue you have is you are misinterpreting what `+(NSString *)stringWithCharacters:length:` is supposed to do. It's not supposed to repeat the characters, but instead copy them from the array into a string.

So in your case you only have a single ' ' in the array, meaning the other 11 characters will be taken from whatever follows `arrayChars` in memory.

If you want to print out a pattern of n spaces, the easiest way to do that would be to use `-(NSString *)stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:`, i.e creating something like this.

```
NSString *formatString = @"Hello%@World";
NSString *paddingString = [[NSString string] stringByPaddingToLength: n withString: @" " startingAtIndex: 0];
NSLog(formatString, paddingString);
```

Comment: Just note that `-stringByPaddingToLength:` is inherently **SLOW**. It must allocate a buffer that is larger than the size of the current string, copy the contents of the current string, than insert and shift all characters in the string as it goes along. That is why my method is much better performing, as it relies upon extremely fast C-APIs.

Comment: Of course, yet the OP may prefer the more abstract methods for readability and simplicity, bear in mind the issue was with understanding how the API works...

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the fastest method:

```
NSString *spacesWithLength(int nSpaces)
{
    char UTF8Arr[nSpaces + 1];

    memset(UTF8Arr, ' ', nSpaces * sizeof(*UTF8Arr));
    UTF8Arr[nSpaces] = '\0';

    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:UTF8Arr];
}
```

The reason your current code isn't working is because `+stringWithCharacters:` expects an array with a length of characters of 12, while your array is only 1 character in length `{' '}`. So, to fix, you must create a buffer for your array (in this case, we use a `char` array, not a `unichar`, because we can easily `memset` a char array, but not a `unichar` array).

The method I provided above is probably the fastest that is possible with a dynamic length. If you are willing to use GCC extensions, and you have a fixed size array of spaces you need, you can do this:

```
NSString *spacesWithLength7()
{
    unichar characters[] = { [0 ... 7] = ' ' };
    return [NSString stringWithCharacters:characters length:7];
}
```

Unfortunately, that extension doesn't work with variables, so it must be a constant.

Through the magic of GCC extensions and preprocessor macros, I give you.... THE REPEATENATOR! Simply pass in a string (or a char), and it will do the rest! Buy now, costs you only $19.95, operators are standing by! (Based on the idea suggested by @JeremyL)

```
// step 1: determine if char is a char or string, or NSString.
// step 2: repeat that char or string
// step 3: return that as a NSString
#define repeat(inp, cnt) __rep_func__(@encode(typeof(inp)), inp, cnt) 

// arg list: (int siz, int / char *input, int n)
static inline NSString *__rep_func__(char *typ, ...)
{
    const char *str = NULL;
    int n;

    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, typ);

        if (typ[0] == 'i')
            str = (const char []) { va_arg(args, int), '\0' };
        else if (typ[0] == '@')
            str = [va_arg(args, id) UTF8String];
        else
            str = va_arg(args, const char *);

        n = va_arg(args, int);

        va_end(args);
    }

    int len = strlen(str);
    char outbuf[(len * n) + 1];

    // now copy the content
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            outbuf[(i * len) + j] = str[j];
        }
    }

    outbuf[(len * n)] = '\0';
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outbuf];
}
```

Comment: I just hope these kind of methods are built in... I think the TRS-80 Basic had something like `string(" ", 12)` and that will work, and if in Ruby, `" " * 12`... if Objective-C might have something like `@" ".repeat(12)` or something like that built in, that'd be nice. (although Objective-C is already nice)

Comment: @JeremyL I agree. While it is possible to write that efficiently using macros, I don't know how useful it would really be.

Comment: @JeremyL take a look at the macro I just wrote. I allows you to go `repeat("test", 5)` or `repeat('t', 12)`, and will do just what you want, for both C-string and char! (I can add support for NSString as well).

Answer (score 3):

The `stringWithCharaters:length:` method makes an `NSString` (or an instance of a subclass of `NSString`) using the first length characters in the C array. It does not iterate over the given array of characters until it reaches the length.

The output you are seeing is the area of memory 12 Unicode characters long starting at the location of your passed 1 Unicode character array.

This should work.

```
NSLog(@"hello%@world", [NSString stringWithCharacters:"            " length:12]);
```

Comment: In this case, why not just use a `NSString` literal? Hardly easy to read.

Comment: The original question was why this particular method call was not giving the expected results. My example is merely to show how the particular method could be invoked to get the expected results. My answer is to help clarify how this method works. This is such a toy question that I assumed the original poster needs to understand this method. So I did the minimal edit to his code to get the results he was expecting.