# How to print out N spaces in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, the method to print out using

```
console.log("this is %s and %s", foo, bar);
```

works, so it follows some C style, but it doesn't follow

```
console.log("%*s this is %s and %s", 12, foo, bar);
```

where the `%*s` and `12` is to make it print out 12 spaces, as in this question:     [In Objective-C, how to print out N spaces? (using stringWithCharacters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702678/in-objective-c-how-to-print-out-n-spaces-using-stringwithcharacters)

Is there a short, quick way to make it work simply in Javascript?  (say, without using the `sprintf` open source library or writing a function to do it?)

**Update:**, in my case, 12 is actually a variable, such as `(i * 4)`, so that's why it can't be hardcoded spaces inside the string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use Array.join:

```
console.log("%s this is %s and %s", Array(12 + 1).join(" "), foo, bar);
```

Note that you want *N + 1* for the array size.

---

I know you said you dont want functions, but if you do this a lot, an extention method can be cleaner:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(length) {
 return Array(length + 1).join(this);
};
```

This allows you to do:

```
console.log("%s this is %s and %s", " ".repeat(12), foo, bar);
```

Comment: @lanzz Yes, missed that. And I do understand sprintf, but AFAIK console.log does not allow you to repeat characters.

Comment: alexn's solution actually works on my Chrome, Firefox, Safari on a Mac

Comment: @lanzz Console.log does not have the same implementation as sprintf. I do not even use `%*s`.

Comment: this is quite smart.  i guess in some time limited programming competition, being able to do quick tricks like this may get you the first prize vs the second prize

Comment: by the way, did you take some Javascript class in school that makes you so well versed in Javascript and know how to extend the classes in Javascript?  Maybe I got my CS education before the OOP era and most classmate / coworkers I know learn Javascript just by picking up snippets of code

Answer (score 8):

As of 2020 and probably earlier, you can use `' '.repeat(12)`:

```js
console.log(`${' '.repeat(12)}hello`);
console.log(`${' '.repeat(3)}hello`);
```